# How to parse a XML file stored in my google drive but which stands out as a html type?

Tags: google-apps-script, xml-parsing, google-drive-api

How to parse a XML file stored in my google drive but which stands out as a html type ?!

I save on my google Drive cloud a copie of an xml of the source: http://api.allocine.fr/rest/v3/movie?media=mp4-lc&partner=YW5kcm9pZC12Mg&profile=large&version=2&code=265621
 I can parsing the source but i cant'xml parsing the copie that look like a html type !!
  i have parsing error  like:  The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag ""
   or Element type "a.length" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"
 I shared it on https://drive.google.com/file/d/16kJ5Nko-waVb8s2T12LaTEKaFY01603n/view?usp=sharing to give you an access and test my script.
 I know that i can using cacheService and it works but for have other control of the buffering i woud try this way

```
function xmlParsingXmlStoreOnGoogleDrive(){
     //So , this is the original xml that is good parsed
 var fetched=UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://api.allocine.fr/rest/v3/movie?media=mp4-lc&partner=YW5kcm9pZC12Mg&profile=large&version=2&code=265621")
 var blob=fetched.getBlob();
 var getAs=blob.getAs("text/xml")
 var data=getAs.getDataAsString("UTF-8")
 Logger.log(data.substring(1,350)); // substring to not saturate the debug display this expected code XML:
 /*
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Copyright © 2019 AlloCiné -->
    <movie code="265621" xmlns="http://www.allocine.net/v6/ns/">
    <movieType code="4002">Long-métrage</movieType>
    <originalTitle>Mise à jour sur Google play</originalTitle>
    <title>Mise à jour sur Google play</title>
    <keywords>Portrait of a Lady on Fire </keywords>
 */
 var xmlDocument=XmlService.parse(data);
 var root=xmlDocument.getRootElement();
 var keywords=root.getChild("keywords",root.getNamespace()).getText();
 Logger.log(keywords);  // Display the expected result :"Portrait of a Lady on Fire "

 // And this my copie of the original xml, that i can't parsing
 var fetched=UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K3-9dHy-h0UoOOY5jYfiSoYPezSi55h1/view?usp=sharing")
 var blob=fetched.getBlob();
 var getAs=blob.getAs("text/xml")
 var data=getAs.getDataAsString("UTF-8")
 Logger.log(data.substring(1,350)); // substring to not saturate the debug display this non expected code HTML !:
 /*
   !DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="google" content="notranslate"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;">
   <style>@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:italic;font-weight:400;src:local('Roboto Italic'),local('Roboto-Italic'),
   url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1Mu51xIIzc.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-fam......
 */
 var xmlDocument=XmlService.parse(data); // ABORT WITH THE ERROR: Element type "a.length" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"
 var root=xmlDocument.getRootElement();
 var keywords=root.getChild("keywords",root.getNamespace()).getText();
 Logger.log(keywords);
}
```

I read on this similar ask :[Parse XML file (which is stored on GoogleDrive) with Google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873647/parse-xml-file-which-is-stored-on-googledrive-with-google-app-script)

that "Unfortunately we can't directly get xml files in the google drive" !! 
Is it right and would that simply mean that I can not realize my script?

Comment: Absolutely Resolved ! :)  And i can't find the button :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wonderful ! You are write. Your two suggestions are working.
I just made a mistake elsewhere in my code. So that solution 1 does not work anymore.
That is why give a new script to test it . For my training only, because my project is safe thanks to you :)

```
function storeXmlOnGoogleDriveThenParsIt(url){
  url=url||"http://api.allocine.fr/rest/v3/movie?media=mp4-lc&partner=YW5kcm9pZC12Mg&profile=large&version=2&code=265621"; // to test
  // on my Google Drive i make a copi of the url called. (This to preserve the server from too many request.)
  var bufferedXml=DriveApp.getRootFolder().searchFolders('title = "BufferFiles"').next().createFile("xmlBuffered.xml", UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText(),MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
  var urlBufferedXml=bufferedXml.getUrl()   // The new url ,of the buffered file
  var fileId=urlBufferedXml.match(/https:\/\/drive.google.com\/file\/d\/(.*)\/view.*/)[1];


  //Now i want to pars the buffered xml file
  //[ Your seconde way to get data is working perect ! THANK YOU A LOT !!!
  var data = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString(); 
  var xmlDocument=XmlService.parse(data);                              
  var root=xmlDocument.getRootElement();
  var mynamespace=root.getNamespace();
  var keywords=root.getChild("keywords",root.getNamespace()).getText();
  Logger.log("keywords:"+keywords)                            // and parsing success ]


  //[ The first way to get data was ok BUT DAMNED it now aborting ! Since modifications on the line code that create the xml, and i cant' retrieve the right code
  var downloadUrlBufferedXml="https://drive.google.com/uc?id="+fileId+"&export=download";
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(downloadUrlBufferedXml).getContentText(); // was good but now data is here again like a html text ! :(
  Logger.log("data"+data.substring(1,350)); // this show that data is HTML type and not XML type !  :(
  var xmlDocument=XmlService.parse(data);  // So i have Error like: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>"  ]
  var root=xmlDocument.getRootElement();
  var mynamespace=root.getNamespace();
  var keywords=root.getChild("keywords",root.getNamespace()).getText();
  Logger.log("keywords:"+keywords)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- You want to retrieve the data from the file on Google Drive and parse as XML data using XmlService.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### Modification points:

- About `var fetched=UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://drive.google.com/file/d/16kJ5Nko-waVb8s2T12LaTEKaFY01603n/view?usp=sharing")`, in this case, the file content cannot be retrieved from this endpoint. If you want to retrieve the file content with UrlFetchApp, please use the endpoint of `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=16kJ5Nko-waVb8s2T12LaTEKaFY01603n&export=download`. This is webContentLink.
- When the file is in your Google Drive and/or shared publicly, you can retrieve the data with the script of `DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString()`.

### Modified script:

For example, when your shared sample file of `https://drive.google.com/file/d/16kJ5Nko-waVb8s2T12LaTEKaFY01603n/view?usp=sharing` is used, the script becomes as follows.

#### Sample script 1:

In this pattern, the file content is retrieved from your shared file with `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`.

```
var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=16kJ5Nko-waVb8s2T12LaTEKaFY01603n&export=download").getContentText(); // Modified
var xmlDocument=XmlService.parse(data);
var root=xmlDocument.getRootElement();
var keywords=root.getChild("keywords",root.getNamespace()).getText();
Logger.log(keywords); // <--- You can see "Portrait of a Lady on Fire" at log.
```

- In this case, the script is required to be shared publicly. If you want to retrieve the file content without sharing, please use the access token for requesting.

#### Sample script 2:

In this pattern, the file content is retrieved from your shared file with `DriveApp.getFileById()`.

```
var fileId = "16kJ5Nko-waVb8s2T12LaTEKaFY01603n"; // Added
var data = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString(); // Added
var xmlDocument=XmlService.parse(data);
var root=xmlDocument.getRootElement();
var keywords=root.getChild("keywords",root.getNamespace()).getText();
Logger.log(keywords); // <--- You can see "Portrait of a Lady on Fire" at log.
```

- `16kJ5Nko-waVb8s2T12LaTEKaFY01603n` of `https://drive.google.com/file/d/16kJ5Nko-waVb8s2T12LaTEKaFY01603n/view?usp=sharing` is the file ID.
- In this case, the file is not required to be shared. But the file is required to be in your Google Drive.

### References:

- [Files of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files)

  > - webContentLink: A link for downloading the content of the file in a browser using cookie based authentication. In cases where the content is shared publicly, the content can be downloaded without any credentials.
- [getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.